# Can I replace default Dual Shock 4 battery to another which has more mAh?

Tags: ps4, controllers

I decided to replace the battery in my Dual Shock 4, because the default is quite weak. After a few hours of using PS4, I get notifications on the screen that the battery is low and I have to charge it.

I read that the default battery has 1000mAh of capacity and I can swap it to another, stronger unit. I looked on the webshops for the new one, but I saw some warnings in descriptions of some batteries, that they are compatible only with DS4 Pro controllers. Is it true? What is the difference between DS4 Pro and the normal DS4. Is the battery socket different?

My controller has id `CUH-ZCT2E` on the sticker.

Comment: If the voltages match and so does the form factor then there should be no issue.

Comment: I have CUH-ZCT2E controller. Is it called "Pro"? I will provide this information to question too.

Comment: Like I said, the form factor and voltage need to match. Besides, what's a DS4?

Comment: DS4 = Dual Shock 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, as long as is about the same voltage and connector.**

First, there is the voltage. A DualShock 4 Battery is 3.65v at 1000mAh, so try to get one with more mAh but same voltage.

Then, there is the connector type. The DS4 comes with one of two types of battery connectors:

- The Big Connector Type (used on the DualShock 3 and DualShock 4 V1)

[image]

- The Small Connector Type (used on the DualShock 4 V2)

[image]

The DualShock 4 controllers that have the big connector can use batteries designed for the DualShock 3 and vice versa (as long as is the same voltage).

If the connector is not the right one, feel free to change it and solder a new one. Just be careful to not puncture the battery with a soldering iron.